# Area of math dealing with the behavior of structures under iteration of some rule?

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics

I am very interested in giving mathematical structures "life" by having them change and interact according to certain sets of rules. I already love cellular automata and have looked into dynamical systems, but actual research in dynamical systems seems too broad in a sense. It steers away from experimenting with the behaviors of concrete specific systems. Even thinking about the Collatz Conjecture could fit under this umbrella, since it is about the behavior of a number under the iteration of a rule.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in [Arithmetic dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_dynamics)
which is a relatively new field which combines dynamics
and arithmetical systems.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [evolutionary game theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_game_theory#:%7E:text=Evolutionary%20game%20theory%20(EGT)%20is,Maynard%20Smith%20and%20George%20R.)!, and specifically replicator equations. This field deals with how systems change under iteration and the math can be applied to far more than biological systems.